# Is my "Magic Find" stat being applied to any monsters still alive when the last seal is opened?

Tags: diablo-ii

I hope this question is not to trivial.. I haven't found any info at Google.

In Diablo II:

When you open the last seal in Chaos Sanctuary, all monsters that are still alive in this area instantly die and after a few seconds Diablo appears at the star.

My question is: when the left over monsters die, does my magic find value apply on these, when they drop items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short  the answer is No.

Magic find doesn't apply there. The magic find only applies to the monsters that you kill with your character (+ your minions eg. skeletons if your necromancer or Valkyrie of amazon). Since the mobs died after diablo arrives and character didn't actually kill those mobs. it were killed by that game trigger. So magic find doesn't apply to those mobs killed by game trigger.